# C++ Project settings in VS 2010

Tags: visual-c++

I’m using VS2010, have one solution with several C++ projects.
How can I set an additional include directory for all projects without going into each project and set it (for debug and release). I have seen the “Inherit from parent or project defaults” checkbox. But don’t understand how to utilize it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Property Manager, you can multi-select all the projects at once and add a new common property sheet. Open up this property sheet and set the Additional Include Directories.

I hope it work!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Visual Studio property sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e.aspx). You can define a property sheet that has the include path and just include it in each project

EDIT:
This link should be very helpful http://blog.gockelhut.com/2009/11/visual-studio-2010-property-sheets-and.html